What is the most natural bijection between even and odd permutations?
Given that $2|A_n|=|S_n|$ it is clear that $S_n\setminus A_n$, which is the set of odd permutations, has the same cardinality as $|A_n|$.
I cannot think of an easy bijection between these two sets that don't require arbitrarily choosing a distinguished element, only maps $\sigma\mapsto\sigma^2$ which is clearly not a bijection.
Given one $\sigma\in S_n\setminus A_n$ it is easy to construct a bijection (namely $\alpha\mapsto\sigma^{-1}\alpha$) such that $\sigma\mapsto\mathbf{1}$.
But I'm inclined to think that no "natural" (both in a categorial and a common sense) bijection exists because that would mean that some distinguished odd-permutation is sent to/comes from the identity, and I don't think $S_n\setminus A_n$ has such an element. How could I make this idea rigorous?
I would like an answer that is valid generally for subgroups of index $2$ if poosible.
Thanks!

There really can't be a natural choice in the exact same way there is no natural choice for coset representatives in $G/H$.  To make this precise, you  need to say natural with respect to what (in other words, define your categories and functors)?  [And then proceed to show that's not possible.]

It's also sort of interesting to phrase precisely what it means for there to be no natural choice of coset reps.  You can write down what this should mean, and then you can show when $H \neq {e}$ there can be no such choice.  I'm trying to do the same thing for your situation, but I'm getting curiously stuck.

One obstruction to the existence of any such natural bijection for a commonsense notion of "natural" is that for $n\geq 3$ the $S_{n}$-set of even permutations of $n$ acted upon by conjugation is not isomorphic to the $S_{n}$-set of odd permutations of $n$ acted upon by conjugation. (Because the former has a fixed point but the latter doesn't.)

You've observed that, once you choose an odd permutation $\sigma$, you can easily define a bijection, $a\mapsto\sigma a$. It goes the other way too: Given a bijection $b:A_n\to S_n\setminus A_n$, you can easily define an odd permutation, namely $b(1)$ where $1$ is the identity permutation. Intuitively, the information needed to define such a bijection is exactly the same as the information needed to define a particular odd permutation.

These are two perfectly valid answers to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.
